# How to reinitialize the lines counter for algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, line-numbering, algorithmicx

I have four algorithms in a section but the problem is that the lines numbering doesn't start with 1 in each algorithm. For example, the first one is numbered from 1 to 11 but the second one start with line number 12 rather than 1. I want to know how can I reinitialize the lines counter for each algorithm to have lines numbers starting with 1?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[ruled,algo2e,french]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{amsmath,color,soulutf8,longtable,colortbl,setspace,ifthen,xspace,url,pdflscape} 
\makeatletter
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}  
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwInput{Initialization}{Initialisation}
        \LinesNumbered
        \Initialization{}   
    \For{}{}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \SetKwInput{Initialization}{Initialisation}
    \LinesNumbered
    \Initialization{}
    \For{}{}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86715/change-line-numbering-in-algorithmics-package. Also: please provide a complete code example (Minimal Working Example, MWE) to show the problem, this makes it easier to offer solutions.

Comment: You can [edit your post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/311789/edit) and paste it in your original post. Without that information, there's not really anything we can do.

Comment: I tried the command \setcounter{ALG@line}{1} but It didn't change any thing.

Answer (score 4):

Use this simple code: `\setcounter{AlgoLine}{<number>}`. The Alg@`line` is incorrect. You should use `Algoline`

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwInput{Initialization}{Initialisation}
        \LinesNumbered
        \Initialization{}   
    \For{}{}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \setcounter{AlgoLine}{0}
    \SetKwInput{Initialization}{Initialisation}
    \LinesNumbered
    \Initialization{}
    \For{}{}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix the use of the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which provides an `algorithm` environment/float) with [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). Use either the one, or the other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetKwInput{Initialization}{Initialisation}
  \LinesNumbered
  \Initialization{}
  \For{}{}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
  \SetKwInput{Initialization}{Initialisation}
  \LinesNumbered
  \Initialization{}
  \For{}{}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that since you're only using `algorithm2e` interface, there's no need to use the `algo2e` package option.

---

If you must use them together, for whatever reason, you need to use the `algo2e` package option and explicitly set `algorithm2e`-style algorithms inside an `algorithm2e` environment, and [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)-style algorithms inside an `algorithm` environment.