Set the line number in algorithm2e
As the title specifies it: Is there a way to reset the line number of a single algorithm when using algorithm2e? My use case is to start line numbering of an algorithm from 26.
Non working minimal example
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetLine{26}
$i \leftarrow 0$
\caption{Sample algorithm.}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}

(I was advised to use \SetLine{N} by ChatGPT.)

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz A moment.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done!

Don't ask or take advice from ChatGPT, it is often mistaken. Search for existing questions instead, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311789/how-to-reinitialize-the-lines-counter-for-algorithms contains the correct answer (as also mentioned by samcarter below).

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{25}
$i \leftarrow 0$
\caption{Sample algorithm.}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}


